# UIRefreshControl doesn't clear the tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am trying to set up a pull to refresh function. The refresh works like it should.
I set up the refreshControl in the followig way:

```
let refreshControlAnimation = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(refreshControlAnimation, action: #selector(handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
self.tableView?.addSubview(refreshControlAnimation)
```

I set up a target and execute the handleRefresh function with a pull.

```
  func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        DataController().fetchDataLive(mode: "get", completionHandler: { success in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        })

    }
```

However, if I pull the refresh animation gets executed but it doesn't end at the time it should. Like you can see on the picture, the animation is still getting executed under the section header.
[image]

But it should be cleared sooner, like in this image.
[image]

Why is my endRefreshing function not called sooner?

Comment: Do you use a UITableViewController ?

Comment: Yes, i use a TableViewController

Comment: Do you execute the code in the main queue ?

Comment: @GaétanZ I was thinking about this issue. So you mean that it could be possible, that the table view is reloaded to fast?

Comment: I did not understand your problem very well actually. But not executing UI code on the main queue can lead to unpredictable behavior. And it is quick common to forget the dispatch async after fetching data.

Comment: @GaétanZ But in my code I only execute the tableview.reloadData, so I don't fetch new data yet. It just looks like the table view doesn't care about the UIRefreshControl

Comment: A bit of your code could be helpful

Comment: @GaétanZ So I updated my code and now I fetch the data when i pull down. I also added a completion handler. The table gets reloaded but it seems like the endRefreshing gets executed too late.

Comment: If fetchDataLive runs in background it could be possible that you just have to run your code on the main thread with something like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() })`.. and also for the tableview reload

Comment: how did you insert the refresh control in the the tableviewcontroller ? can we code snippet for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got your problem. Refresh control should not be added as a subview, because swift has already done a provision of adding it to the tableview/tableviewcontrollers.

use:-

```
self.tableView.refreshControl = yourRefreshControl
```

Comment: Oh yes, just got it. Solved it with creating an extra variable. But your version would work as well. Didn't quite understand the concept of it in the beginning.